# Content of button is not updated after changing the CurrentUICulture

Tags: wpf, .net-core, multilingual, resx, .net-core-3.1

According to [this tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/299436/WPF-Localization-for-Dummies), I try to implement the multilingual system to my WPF .NET Core 3.1 application. Everything works fine if I change the property `Title` of `Window` element directly, application reads from the corrent resource file, which is is defined by changing the `CurrentUICulture`.

Here is a code of such a change:

```
private void BtnChangeLanguageToCsCz_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("cs-CZ");
}

private void BtnChangeLanguageToEnUs_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
}
```

However after I click any of these buttons, their content remains unupdated. I feel like I need to call some UI update function or anything like this but can't find anything related so far.

Here is how do I bind the `Content` property of the `Button`:

```
<Button x:Name="BtnInstall" Content="{x:Static p:Resource.ButtonInstall}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,324,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="50" Width="200" Click="BtnInstall_Click"/>
```

Resource files have their modifiers set to public and here are the names:

[image]

What should I do to make it update itself?

Comment: there are no *.Designer.cs files for the files with suffix, because one Resources class is enough: it loads resource according to application current culture from corresponding .resx file. your .resx files should contain translations in xml format, e.g. `<data name="LongWheelName" xml:space="preserve"><value>Long Wheel Name Translation</value></data>`

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/299436/WPF-Localization-for-Dummies

Comment: @ASh Thank you for the tutorial, it really helped. I have rewrited the question.

Comment: Make sure the Build Action of the other resource files are "Embedded Resource"

Comment: @ReeceRussell All the resource files are `Embedded Resource` and the `Copy to Output Directory` value is `Do not copy`, shoudl I change it?

Comment: @Chyuae, `{x:Static }` expression is never updated. I used this localization approach, and it was fine until I needed switch cultures in runtime. so I came up with [my own solution, based on resources](https://github.com/AlexanderSharykin/LibraryCommander/tree/master/Src/LibraryCommander/Localization) - [mainly part is this](https://github.com/AlexanderSharykin/LibraryCommander/blob/master/Src/LibraryCommander/Localization/LocalizationProvider.cs)

Comment: I wonder why there is no .NET built-in solution for this.

Comment: such requirement is somewhat rare. often culture is set once during installation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A found a solution based on [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/dynamic-localization-in-wpf/) tutorial, and rather than using the thread's culture or resource.resx files, it uses XAML resource dictionaries.

This can be changed for your case, however, I did this for my MainWindow.xaml:

- I created two resource dictionaries called 'MainWindow.en-GB.xaml' and 'MainWindow.cs-CZ.xaml', in a folder named `/Resources`.
- I then set the build action to `Content` and the Copy to Output Directory to `Copy if newer`.
- Once I created the resource dictionaries, I created an example resource called `Text`:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
        <sys:String x:Key="Text">Hello</sys:String>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

- Then in my MainWindow.xaml, I added the following code:

```
<Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/MainWindow.en-GB.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
```

- Followed by, setting the button's content to the resource `Text`:

```
<Button x:Name="BtnInstall" 
    Content="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=Text}" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
    Margin="0,324,0,0" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" 
    Height="50" 
    Width="200" 
    Click="BtnInstall_Click" />
```

- Finally, by using the `LocUtil` from the [linked tutorial](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/dynamic-localization-in-wpf/), calling the `LocUtil.SwitchLanguage` method, I could change between the two:

```
private void BtnChangeLanguageToEnUs_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    LocUtil.SwitchLanguage(this, "en-US");
}
```

Comment: I have been getting error while adding `<ResourceDisctionary>` section into the `MainWindow.xaml`, application works fine even without this part of code in it.

Comment: Yes, I'm unable to find any issue.

Comment: Perfect, hope it all goes well!

Comment: I always thought that uploading images takes more effort and less convenient than inserting block of code. But people always do it anyway. I wonder why?

Comment: @Ash I agree, less convenient; however, I was having issues using the code editor with XML/XAML where it either wouldn't display correctly or at all.

Comment: @ReeceRussell, that happens to xml which is not properly formatted: it should have either triple ` (```) or 4 spaces in front. otherwise it is interpreted as html, but xaml tags don't have visual representation in web, so they end up rendered empty

Comment: @Ash that makes sense! They kept getting rendered empty or missing tags, but thanks for the pointers!

Comment: @ReeceRussell, click "edit" under any post question/answer with xaml in it and you will see formatting

Comment: @ReeceRussell Brilliant!